# Find entries of one text file in another file in python

Tags: python, string, compare, readfile

I have two files. File **A** has some entries in each line and I need to find if any entry is found in File **B**. Here is my script (using two functions):

```
def readB(x):
 with open('B.txt') as resultFile:
    for line in resultFile:
        if x in line:
            print x


def readA():
 with open('A.txt') as bondNumberFile:
    for line in bondNumberFile:
        readB(line)

readA()
```

This script finds the first entry in second file and then does not finds the next one. What might be wrong here?

File A looks like this:

```
122323 
812549
232335
921020
```

and File B looks like this:

```
696798  727832  750478  784201  812549  838916  870906  890988  921020  
697506  727874  751037  784955  813096  838978  872494  891368  921789  
696798  727832  750478  784201  812549  838916  870906  890988  921020  
697506  727874  751037  784955  813096  838978  872494  891368  921789
```

Comment: The next one might not be there.

Comment: It is there. I have added myself for testing.

Comment: This task can be done by grep as follows: `grep -f fileA fileB`. The best kind of code is the kind you don't have to write. If you're on Windows, you can try `Get-Content fileB | Select-String -Pattern (Get-Content fileA)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Strip the entries of newlines

Python includes newlines when you read lines - your first entry is read as `1223232\n`. Strip the newline and it will work.

```
def readA():
    with open('A.txt') as bondNumberFile:
        for line in bondNumberFile:
            readB(line.rstrip())
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need to define functions to do this

```
with open('a.txt') as a, open('b.txt') as b:
    result = set(a.readlines()) & set(b.readlines())
```

If they both have the same line, it will return them in a set.

If you *really* wanted a function, you could write it like this

```
def compare(file1: str, file2: str) -> set:
    with open(file1) as f1, open(file2) as f2:
        return set(f1.readlines()) & set(f2.readlines())
```

Comment: The name 'check' was typo.

Comment: Your solution still does not solve my problem. Please check the question again. I have added files data as well.

Comment: None of the numbers in file A match with the file B. Also, if you're trying to match all of the numbers listed, you'd want to change `readlines()` to `read().split()`

Comment: The numbers do not match because this is just a test data. But let me edit it.