# Algorithm for measuring the similarity of two text files with different sizes

Tags: nlp, text-mining

Suppose there are two files A and B, A is a huge data file with a size over 1GB (in text, no internal uniform data structure for the data). B is a file which might contain a small potion of data from A, and has a size below 1KB. I need an algorithm to measure how much data does B have can also be found in A. The more the data B contains is taken from A, the higher score this algorithm should return.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this ...

```
def readA():
with open('A.txt') as bondNumberFile:
    for line in bondNumberFile:
        readB(line.rstrip())
```

Also, you don't necessarily need to define functions to do this. Something like below can also be done.

```
with open('a.txt') as a, open('b.txt') as b:
result = set(a.readlines()) & set(b.readlines())
```

You might find [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37967337/find-entries-of-one-text-file-in-another-file-in-python) useful.
Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your post, but I am afraid the problem is more complicated. Simply obtaining the intersection of two bag-of-words sets may not solve the problem. Suppose we have a data entry in A records Paul:Male, by using bag-of-words method, we can get a set of two words Paul and Male, which may appear many times in B. Only when the two words are closely related in B, we report a duplication. I am afraid this algorithm can not do this.